# No response from remote desktop when connecting via ssh

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a Jetson TX2 running Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using ifconfig on my Jetson to figure out the ip adress on to which I want to connect to.

then, using this adress, I do:
    ssh nvidia@ipadress

but nothing happens.  Theres no feedback, no error message but just an empty line with my cursor blinking. I can type anything and press enter, with no effect. 'exit' doesn't stop that either, only ctrl c would. So when I do the above I get (on my host pc):

```
n@HPZ240:~$ ssh nvidia@10.4.61.106
```

where below this line nothing happens until I press ctrl C.

However, if I'm on my Jetson, I can connect to my host PC just like that. So it works from my Jetson to the Host PC but not the otherway round. Both PCs run Ubuntu 16.04.

Can anyone help? I read related posts and checked everything (firewall settings

```
 service ssh status
```

etc...and all seems to be correct to me.

thanks!

Comment: Whether `ssh -vvv nvidia@10.4.61.106` provides some information?